# Resolving MySQL Deadlock issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

**Service**: We have a service that receives `Request` and it just saves it in the database. Following is hbm file for same.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.project.dao">
        <class name="Request" table="requests">
                <id name="requestId" type="long" column="req_id">
                        <generator class="native" />
                </id>
        <class>
        <discriminator column="req_type" type="string" force="true"/>
        <property name="status" type="string" column="status"/>
        <property name="processId" type="string" column="process_id"/>
        <subclass name="RequestType1" discriminator-value="Type1">
          ..
        </subclass>     
        <subclass name="RequestType2" discriminator-value="Type2">
          ..
        </subclass>     
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code which obtains session and saves `Request` is as follows.

```
try{
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  requestDAO.save(request);
  tx.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
  log.error(e);
}
```

**Client**: There are two hosts on client side that reads these received and unprocessed request. Each client(Host1, Host2) does following.

Update process_id of unprocessed request to its hostname.

```
update requests set process_id='" + hostName + "' where status='Received' and process_id is null order by req_id asc limit 100"
```

Retrieve requests updated above and process them.

```
select * from requests where process_id='"+ hostName + "' where status='Received';
```

Now problem is, for some time, these clients would work fine. But after some time, they start throwing following exception.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query at  org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Client again starts to work normally if we restart them.

On service side also, we see following exceptions sometimes.

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id don't flush the Session after an exception occurs
```

We have been trying to resolve this issue but not able to figure out root cause. Any insight into the probable issue would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be possible that while saving request in `requestDAO.save(req)` , it acquires AUTO_INC lock but does not release this lock if save operation fails.

Comment: Save operation on service side fails at `tx.commit()` resulting in this 'null id assertion failure` exception.

Comment: Would using spring transaction annotations help here instead of beginning/committing transaction ourselves?

Comment: Also is there a way to retry in case of failed transactions due to deadlock issues like above when using spring transaction manager?